# About the space in iPhone app name when upload

Tags: iphone

In the targets settings, I set the "Product Name" to be "My first app" (for instance), and this name will be displayed on the iPhone.

But when I upload the app, apple complains that the name the name of app can't contain the space. Can I just rename the app from "My first app.app" to "Myfirstapp.app"? Will that impact on the name displayed on the iPhone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the file has no impact on how it's displayed in the app. So don't worry about it. Just nix the spaces, that's what I've done with one of my apps on the store, name displays fine.

Answer (score 3):

The name to be displayed to user is defined by "`Bundle Display Name`", in the .plist file.